# Graph with loop which does not display in streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, streamlit

i try to do a spyder graph for my streamlit app. However, it functions on my notebook but not in my streamlit. Is anyone has an idea of the problem it does not display anything ?

```
Spider_kmeans = df[['Cluster_kmeans_Label','Age','Annual Income (k$)','Spending Score (1-100)','Sex (100=Male)']]
Spider_kmeans = Spider_kmeans.groupby('Cluster_kmeans_Label')['Cluster_kmeans_Label','Age','Annual Income (k$)','Spending Score (1-100)','Sex (100=Male)'].mean().reset_index()


def make_spider_kmeans( row, title, color):
 
    # number of variable
    categories=list(Spider_kmeans)[1:]
    N = len(categories)

    # What will be the angle of each axis in the plot? (we divide the plot / number of variable)
    angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
    angles += angles[:1]

    # Initialise the spider plot
    ax = plt.subplot(3,3,row+1, polar=True)

    # If you want the first axis to be on top:
    ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

    # Draw one axe per variable + add labels labels yet
    plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='black',fontfamily='serif',fontweight='light', size=8)
    #ax.set_xticks([]) # turn labels off if you want - can look quite nice

    # Draw ylabels
    ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
    plt.yticks([10,20,30,40,50,75,100], ["10","20","30","40","50","75","100"], color="grey", size=4)
    plt.ylim(0,100)

    # Ind1
    values= Spider_kmeans.loc[row].drop('Cluster_kmeans_Label').values.flatten().tolist()
    values += values[:1]
    ax.plot(angles, values, color=color, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid')
    ax.fill(angles, values, color=color, alpha=0.4)

    # Add a title
    plt.title(title, size=10, fontfamily='serif',fontweight='bold', y=1.2)
    plt.tight_layout()

#############################################################################################

my_dpi=96

plt.figure(figsize=(1000/my_dpi, 1000/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
 
# Create a color palette:
my_palette = plt.cm.get_cmap("crest", len(df.index))
```

then i put this code on my streamlit app

```
for row in range(0, len(Spider_kmeans.index)):
    make_spider_kmeans( row=row, title='Cluster: '+ Spider_kmeans['Cluster_kmeans_Label'][row], color='#244747') #change this to my_palette if you want colour to vary by cluster
```

I

Comment: How did you implement it on streamlit?  And what output do you expect when using streamlit?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've used the Streamlit library in this code snippet. Can you share the full code?